# Протестировать процедуру в макросе Microsoft Project

Tags: vba, project-management

Я работаю с Microsoft Project 2013. На мою просьбу написать макрос, «товарищ» ответил мне следующей процедурой:

```
Sub Macro1()
    n = InputBox("Input Name of the New task")
    a = CInt(InputBox("Input duration of subtask a"))
    b = CInt(InputBox("Input duration of subtask b"))
    Set oTask = ActiveProject.Tasks.Add(n)
    Application.SetTaskField "Number1", a, , , oTask.ID
    Application.SetTaskField "Number2", b, , , oTask.ID
    Application.SetTaskField "Duration", oTask.Number1 + oTask.Number2, , , oTask.ID
End Sub
```

Однако при попытке обработать данную процедуру пошагово с помощью клавиши <kbd>F8</kbd> мой Project «спотыкается» на предпоследней строчке, а именно:

```
Application.SetTaskField "Duration", oTask.Number1 + oTask.Number2, , , oTask.ID
```

И выскакивает ошибка:

> Run-time error "1004": непредвиденная ошибка метода.

Но на данном этапе вопрос даже не в том, почему выскакивает это ошибка.
Пожалуйста помогите протестировать данную процедуру на вашей установленной версии Project-е. Потому, что товарищ клянется, что на его компе всё происходит «без сучка и задоринки».

Возможно, ошибка с моим Project-ом?